# Update function for SingleViewApplication

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, overriding

I have always used `SpriteKit` to create mobile applications. I want to start using `SingleViewApplication`. I know that in `SpriteKit`, there is a built in Update Function that updates every frame. I was wondering if there is something like this that I can use for `SingleViewApplications`. Here is how the update function looks like in `SpriteKit`:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
}
```

I was thinking that I can add an `NSTimer` that update as much as the update function does, but I was thinking that it may add lag to the app.

Also, when I add this code in my `ViewController`, it gives me an error saying that `this method does not override any methods form its superclass`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Anton, in SpriteKit - for creating games -  you usually have many objects moving around and therefore there is a function "update" as you already know. When you don't use SpriteKit you don't have a standard function "update", thats why you get the error message "this method does not override any methods form its superclass." You better explain more, what do you want to update in your single view app, what objects do want to show ?

Comment: @LukeSideWalker Thanks for responding! I want to basically check while the user is typing on a UITextField if the user has applied certain constraints. Ex: Checking if username is already taken, ...

Comment: OK in this case you should check the delegate pattern in generell. This means your could make your viewController being a delegate of the UITextField, being informed about a lot of things happens with the UITextField while the User is typing on it. Maybe you check the docs, it's a huge topic at the beginning, but if you understand the delegate pattern in generell, you'll soon be able to use the UITextFieldDelegate methods. Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate

Comment: @LukeSideWalker Thanks, I'll have a look on that!